# Laravel Custom Model Class - Field Does not have a Default Value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

So, I have a custom `Model` extension class called `RecursiveModel`:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use ... RecursiveHelper;

class RecursiveModel extends Model {
    private $recursiveHelper = null;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->recursiveHelper = new RecursiveHelper();

        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function save(array $options = []){
        parent::save($options);
    }

    ...

    // Additional methods available for Recursive Models (self-referenced `parent_id` relationships)
}
```

And, a `Model` that extends this `RecursiveModel` class instead of the base `Model` class:

```
use ... RecursiveModel;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Line extends RecursiveModel {

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = "lines";
    protected $primaryKey = "id";

    public function parent(){
        return $this->belongsTo(self::class, "parent_id", "id");
    }

    public function children(){
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, "parent_id", "id");
    }
}
```

All is well and good, and with previously imported records (back when `Line` extended `Model` and not `RecursiveModel`, I was able to use my `RecursiveHelper` methods/logic without issue. Now, I'm trying to refresh my database, which calls a `Seeder`:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use ... Slugger;
use ... Line;

class LinesSeeder extends Seeder {
    public function run(){
        $parentLine = Line::create([
            "name" => "Line Item",
            "slug" => $this->slugger->slugify("Line Item"),
            "created_at" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
            "updated_at" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        ]);

        $childLine = Line::create([
            "name" => "Child Line Item",
            "slug" => $this->slugger->slugify("Child Line Item"),
            "parent_id" => $parentLine->id,
            "created_at" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
            "updated_at" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        ]);

        ... 
    }
}
```

As previously stated, when `Line` extended `Model` and not `RecursiveModel`, this code worked without issue. But now, I'm running into this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `lines`
>      (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2018-08-13 15:56:45, 2018-08-13 15:56:45))

The `Line::create([...]);` doesn't seem to be receiving the parameter passed; is there something I'm missing when extending `Model.php`? I've tried adding:

```
public function create(array $options = []){
    parent::create($options);
}
```

To `RecursiveModel`, but that just throws another error (and I don't think the `create()` method is a part of `Model.php`, but rather `Builder.php`.)

Also, it's not an issue with `protected $fillable`, nor is it an issue with setting `'strict' => true,` on my `mysql` connection; already tried both of those to no avail.

As suggested, updated `__construct` method of `RecursiveModel` to:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = []){
    $this->recursiveHelper = new RecursiveHelper();

    return parent::__construct($attributes);
}
```

Unfortunately, still getting the same error.

Edit: `Line.php` had a `__construct` method that was carried over from when I was applying `$this->recursiveHelper` model by model; solution was to update signature to match (as noted above) or remove `__construct` from extending models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model constructors need to take in an array of attributes:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
```

Comment: Oh nvm; added it to `Line.php`; now it works. Will update my code and get this closed. Thanks! (Alternatively, removed `__construct` from `Line.php`, since I'm not overriding anything)